# Xamarin CustomRenderer in ListView

Tags: c#, listview, xamarin, custom-renderer

I have a `ListView` that have a custom view inside it `ViewCell`.

This custom view is a `Label` that render an HTML content.

All works, except when a `ViewCell` exit from the screen the label lost th HTML format and show the HTML tags.

[image]

This is the custom renderer in IOS (same problem on Android):

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(LabelHtmlView), typeof(LabelHtmlCustomRenderer))]

namespace SgatMobileV2.iOS {
    public class LabelHtmlCustomRenderer : LabelRenderer {

    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Label> e) {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        var View = (LabelHtmlView)Element;
        if (View == null) return;

        var Attribute = new NSAttributedStringDocumentAttributes();
        var NsError = new NSError();

        Attribute.DocumentType = NSDocumentType.HTML;

        Control.AttributedText = new NSAttributedString(View.Text, Attribute, ref NsError);

    }

}
```

}

This is the ListView code:

```
<ListView x:Name="ListaRigheWo" CachingStrategy="RecycleElement"
    HasUnevenRows="True" SeparatorVisibility="Default" 
    ItemsSource="{Binding ListaWORighe}">
    [...]
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <Grid>
                    [...]
                        <view:LabelHtmlView 
                          Text="{Binding DescrizioneIntervento}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" 
                          Grid.ColumnSpan="4" Style="{StaticResource LblValore}" />
```

How can I solve this?

Thank you!

Comment: looks like its caused by the listview virtualization some how, does it do the same if use ListViewCachingStrategy.RetainElement ?

Comment: If I set ListViewCachingStrategy.RetainElement the format remains right. But the list can have many elements, so  I need to use RecycleElement :(

Comment: I think you will have to try a lot of trial and error in your renderer and may need to make a custom listview renderer to poke at your custom label, virtualisation problems can be fickle to say the least

Comment: For now I set RetainElement :/

Comment: Yeah, if speed is a problem try and optimize your xaml, there are some great videos and resources or the cyclic calculations xamarin.forms performs and ow you can pinch every bit of speed you can